# Are 3rd party CAPTCHA techniques vulnerable to MITM attacks?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, captcha

Presume I'm a bad actor and want to do a naughty thing on a site protected by some 3rd party CAPTCHA solution. For instance, perhaps I'm a spammer who wants some way to script sign-ups to Hotmail.

For the target site to use CAPTCHA, it presumably must load a javascript file from the CAPTCHA provider's server. Since I'm in control of the browser (and DNS etc) what's to stop me substituting my own javascript instead? And if I can swap in my own script, what's to stop me "short-circuiting" the CAPTCHA to be immediately solved?

Out of curiosity, I did some Googling. I found that there are indeed some providers who claim they can defeat CAPTCHAs, but interestingly these providers all seem to use humans to do the solving. (Basing this on the fact that they all offer a sign-up option for workers as well as clients.)

What is the defence mechanism against the sort of attack I've described?

Comment: This would work if your computer is telling the remote server that you solved the captcha, but it isn't. Google is telling the remote server that you solved the captcha (maybe through your computer via a token, but it's a token that your computer can't forge).

Comment: Ah that's interesting. So the communication is going from the browser, to Google, to the service provider's server?

Comment: Not entirely sure about how Google's captcha system works, but ultimately the web server will receive a token that was generated by Google (either directly from Google, or bundled with the data that the client sends) that signifies that the client completed the captcha.

Comment: According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51507695/google-recaptcha-v3-example-demo) it looks like the web client will get the token and add it into the form when it uploads to the web server.

Comment: @user That would seem to still be vulnerable to a substitution attack then, if a bad actor controlled the web client?

Comment: It's not vulnerable to token substitution because due to crypto magic only Google can generate valid tokens.

Comment: @user But Google will dish out a valid token if the script tells it to? My thinking goes like this: if the script is the thing that mediates between the website and the CAPTCHA provider, and if a bad actor can substitute the script, surely there's some weakness?

Comment: The client doesn't verify the captcha, Google does. When you solve the captcha you send your results/guess to Google. If Google is happy with your answer then it sends you the token.

Comment: Right, but who tells the service that Google was happy with the result? If there's no direct communication (i.e. not mediated via a script running in the browser) between the service and the CAPTCHA provider, how can it be secure?

Comment: The token tells the service that Google was happy with the result. It's a cryptographic token so it can't be forged.

Comment: And then the calling service relying on CAPTCHA verifies that token on their server? Or does the script do the validation and return a bool?

Comment: Looks like the web server will send the captcha token that it got from the client (+ secret used for authentication etc.) to Google, Google then sends a response with a pass/fail (`$response->success`) boolean. I'm assuming Google also handles timeouts (2 minutes from that previous stack question) and replay attacks.

Comment: Interesting! Well, if you felt like typing some of this up as an answer, I'd be very minded to accept it.

Comment: If nobody else wants to write one up then I can once my shift is over.

Comment: Just a note here: there are a lot of different types of CAPTCHAS... the ones that have to be solved by humans (because of Bot detection) will transmit a one-time use token.  So those 3rd party services will solve it, but never use the token.  They then pass the token to their client and they use it (presumably in their bot) to pass the CAPTCHA.

Comment: further, a MITM won't prevent the site from detecting the bot.  Those methods are separate from solving the captcha.  (with Google's, you'll solve the puzzle over and over but you just get another puzzle... it knows you are a bot and just keeps presenting new ones.)  So bot-detection is a separate beast.  The reason those 3rd party services work is they are not detected as a bot, so they receive a proper token/key.

Comment: one more note (sry): the puzzle itself often doesn't have an answer.  There is no right or wrong, but some human input that is collected and sometimes used to fuel AI.  So often they're not really looking for anything all that specific to be sent back.  Just a human response.  I believe the inventor won a prize because it became a sort of crowd-sourced way of digitizing books.  (for words the OCR couldn't recognize)

Answer (score 2):

The solution is to never trust clients to execute code. If everything is done server-side, there is no possibility of a MITM attack, since you can just cryptographically sign the token that says "Yes, User X did complete the CAPTCHA at this time". As soon as you add in authentication, MITM becomes incredibly difficult.

You can substitute your own JS, but the website you are trying to spam won't let you finish the signup process because it expects a signed token from the CAPTCHA server. Without access to the private key, a client cannot create these tokens.

Answer (score 0):

@Expectator has the right of it, but I wanted to elaborate a little bit on how third party CAPTCHA servers work and why your plan to bypass them would fail.

In your plan, you say that you are "in control of the browser" ... but this is making an assumption that the only communication is between your client and the target server.  This is a bad assumption as there is actually a 3 way communication happening:

- client <---> target server
- client <---> CAPTCHA server
- target server <---> CAPTCHA server

The connection between the target server and the CAPTCHA server could be a direct connection or it could be done via a shared secret using your browser as a proxy between them ... in either case, your not going to be able to bypass it simply be changing the javascript presented by the 3rd party CAPTCHA provider.

Comment: Actually, it was my realisation that (at least) ReCAPTCHA v3 doesn't use direct target server<--->CAPTCHA server communication that sparked this question. See their installation guide: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/v3

Comment: As I stated, it can go `direct target server<--->CAPTCHA` or it can go `via a shared secret using your browser as a proxy` both are possible.  Even if its via a shared secret ... client side wont know what that shared secret is ... which means your still not going to get around it.